# How to detect the page handle in my observer?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, regex

I want to avoid the execution of my observer in case the page handle contains checkout or catalog, how could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method below.

```
    public function __construct(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request){
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){
            $handle = $this->_request->getFullActionName();
            $regexRule = '/checkout|catalog/';
            
            // If the page's handle contains the values in the Regex, skip the Observer
            if (preg_match($regexRule, $handle)) {
                return;
            }
    }
```